# jsdoc @link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Im using jsdoc 3.4.3 and i tried to use @link to link to internal @typedef that iv'e done

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Color
 * @property {string} [attr] - attribute name corresponding to an outcome event
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Config
 * ..
 * ..
 * ..
 * @property {Color} [l.lC=Color] - coloring specification for the nodes as defined in {@link Color}
 * @property {Color} [l.nC=Color] - coloring specification for the links as defined in {@link Color}
 */
```

this is a documentation of a javascript file.
can some see the problem (or know about known problem with @link)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe e.g.

```
@see [Color](module-Color.html)
```

Also, check your configuration for cleverLinks and monospaceLinks